# Provide code coverage for blazor inline code

Tags: blazor, code-coverage, coverlet

I've got code like this in a blazor component...

```
<MyComponent OnSomeEvent="@((id) => SomeMethod(id)" />
```

Now coverlet says that this line isn't tested.

In the containing control I'm testing that the delegate is called, and I have tests covering `MyComponent.SomeMethod` in the `MyComponent.razor.cs` file, but I can neither prevent Coverlet from saying this code isn't covered or find a way of excluding this line from code coverage.

Any suggestions about what I'm missing would be gratefully received.

Comment: Suggestion - If `OnSomeEvent` returns the same pattern as `SomeMethod`, why not  call `SomeMethod` directly?  If not then call it through an defined intermediary method, and see what happens.

Comment: Just to check, arer you using bUnit ?  That should be able to exercise this.